# Linking multiple lists with a variable

Tags: python

I'm trying to link multiple lists with a variable. With the output being an item from one of the 'multiple' lists. The variable needs to have the name of the list. So that the index of the item in the one list is the same as the index of the item in one of the others. Sorry if it's a duplicate, but I couln't find anything that I can understand.

```
creature_type = "easy"
creature_type = "medium"
creature_type = "hard"

list1 = ['slime', 'dog', 'chicken']
list2 = ['orc', 'wolf']
list3 = ['dragon', 'golem', 'vampire']

attack4 = ['spits juice', 'bites', 'pecks']
attack5 = ['slams', 'howls']
attack6 = ['breaths fire', 'throws rocks', 'transforms']
```

With as output the attack for the creature in the first three lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dictionaries and `zip`:

```
creatures = {'easy': ['slime', 'dog', 'chicken'],
             'medium': ['orc', 'wolf'],
             'hard': ['dragon', 'golem', 'vampire']}

attacks = {'easy': ['spits juice', 'bites', 'pecks'],
           'medium': ['slams', 'howls'],
           'hard': ['breaths fire', 'throws rocks', 'transforms']}

choice = 'medium'

linked = list(zip(creatures[choice], attacks[choice]))
```

Output:

```
[('orc', 'slams'), ('wolf', 'howls')]
```

Comment: Does it also work to print only one item from the lists? Btw thx for answering

Comment: Try `linked[0]` for the first item. Not exactly sure what you want to do.

Comment: Trying to just have the attack printed, but if it works like that it's fine

Comment: `linked[0][1]` but then I'm not sure why you want to link the list...

Comment: Maybe you want a dictionary? `linked = dict(zip(creatures[choice], attacks[choice]))` then `linked['orc']`

Comment: It's to desplay the message ex. "slime spits juice at you and did ... damage", what do you recommend? Something I can understand though, bc I don't really get what dict does.

Comment: It's an important concept to understand if you want to learn python. You should read a basic python tutorial to learm the basic structures.